# C++ libraries to store settings in human-readable format

Tags: c++

I have a lot of settings which are represented by key-value pair. Key is a string, value can be string or double. These settings are divided by categories with string names.
The question is - I want to store settings in human-readable format, the file should be easily read and changed by user. (that's why e.g. boost serialization is not so good). What libraries can you recommend?

Comment: `simpleini`, `QSettings` and many more. Or you could write a basic INI file parser yourself in one night.

Comment: See [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be trivially solvable using [JSON](https://www.google.fr/search?q=c%2B%2B+json).

As for library recommendations, it is considered off-topic on SO.